# FacebookOperationCanceledException: Invalid application

Tags: android, facebook-authentication, facebook-access-token

I'm using FB SDK3, my Android app need to get access token.
For that I created the following code:

```
private static class FacebookConnector implements Session.StatusCallback {

        private static FacebookConnector instance = null;
        private Fragment mFragment;
        private Session session;

        public static FacebookConnector getInctance(Fragment fragment) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new FacebookConnector();
            }
            instance.setFragment(fragment);

            return instance;
        }

        private FacebookConnector() {
        }

        /**
         * Set the fragment that make the fb authentication
         * 
         * @param fragment
         */
        public void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            mFragment = fragment;
        }

        /**
         * Connect to facebook
         */
        public void logIn() {
            Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
            session = new Session.Builder(mFragment.getActivity())
                    .setApplicationId("548056975227881")
                    .build();
            session.addCallback(this);
            Session.setActiveSession(session);

            // Login
            if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(mFragment).setCallback(this));
            } else {
                Session.openActiveSession(mFragment.getActivity(), true, this);
            }
        }

        /**
         * @return the access token, null if not exist
         */
        public String getToken() {
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(mFragment).setCallback(this));
            }
            String token = session.getAccessToken();
            System.out.println("TOKEN: " + token);
            return token;
        }

        /**
         * Disconnect from facebook
         */
        public void logOut() {
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (!session.isClosed()) {
                session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            String token = session.getAccessToken();

            Log.d(state.toString(), "Token: " + token);
            if (exception != null) {
                Log.e("FACEBOOK", exception.getMessage(), exception);
            }
            Log.d("", "-----------------------");
        }

    }
```

It's worked fine, until I got that exception:

```
4-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812): Invalid application MY_APP_ID
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812): com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException: Invalid application MY_APP_ID
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812):  at com.facebook.Session.handleAuthorizationResult(Session.java:1043)
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812):  at com.facebook.Session.onActivityResult(Session.java:543)
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812):  at com.maccabi.counteat.ui.welcome.WelcomeFragment.onActivityResult(WelcomeFragment.java:121)
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:161)
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3988)
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2689)
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2735)
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:124)
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:998)
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3844)
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-14 18:32:14.502: E/FACEBOOK(26812):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I cannot uderstand what happens. The only changes I made is at the FB side app and it was
adding Facebook Comment box and accessing that from other Fragment with a WebView.
After I saw the next [article](http://sean.lyn.ch/2011/07/android-the-facebook-sdk-sso-and-you/). I'm debugging my app on my device (not emulator).

If it because FB single sign on or something else?
How can I impelement that changes when I'm running my app on my device?